# How to load JS file in html using express server

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have put my js in a public directory and trying to load the js in my HTML but getting an error.

---

```
var express=require('express');
var bodyparser=require('body-parser');
var path=require("path");
var multer=require("multer");
console.log(__dirname);
var app=express();
var upload = multer({ dest: __dirname + '/uploads/' });
// app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.use(bodyparser.json());
app.use(bodyparser.urlencoded({extended:true}));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
 app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);
app.get('/',(req,res)=>{
     res.render('some.ejs');
});
app.post('/',upload.single('upl'),(req,res)=>{
    console.log(req.body);
    console.log(req.file);
})
app.listen(3000,()=>{
    console.log("server is up");
})
```

---

Here is my HTML code to load the JS:

```
<script src="/public/web.js"></script>
```

directory structure

```
├ public
| └ web.js
├ views
| └ some.ejs
└ server.js
```

Comment: Please include the error message.

Comment: Also after you add express.static as mention in bellow answer you need to change your path like so `<script src="/web.js"></script>` the /public part is not needed.

Answer (score 3):

To serve a file from the server to the client, you must declare the directory as a static.

Using express you can do this using,

`app.use(express.static('PublicDirectoryPath'))`

To fetch the files under the public directory,

`<script src="FilePathUnderPublicDirectory"></script>`

**Updated Code:**

Now your `server.js` file should be

```
var express=require('express');
var bodyparser=require('body-parser');
var path=require("path");
var multer=require("multer");
console.log(__dirname);
var app=express();
app.use(express.static('public'));
var upload = multer({ dest: __dirname + '/uploads/' });
// app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.use(bodyparser.json());
app.use(bodyparser.urlencoded({extended:true}));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
 app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);
app.get('/',(req,res)=>{
     res.render('some.ejs');
});
app.post('/',upload.single('upl'),(req,res)=>{
    console.log(req.body);
    console.log(req.file);
})
app.listen(3000,()=>{
    console.log("server is up");
})
```

> Notice that I declare the public directory as a static directory at
>   line 7.

Since your `web3.js` is directly under the `public` directory, in your front end, use

```
<script src="/web.js"></script>
```

For more, please check the [doc](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html).

Answer (score 1):

To serve static files such as images, CSS files, and JavaScript files, use the express.static built-in middleware function in Express.

```
app.use(express.static('public'))
```

now you can serve static files like js, css and images.